# mysql speed mysql_num_rows vs query limit 1

Tags: php, mysql

i had to check if a value (string) is in my database.

at the moment i do a

`select a.email,b.vuid from user a, verteiler_user b where a.email=\''.$email.'\' and a.kid=' . $kid.' and b.vid=' . $vid . ' and a.uid = b.uid`

as query with a `mysql_num_rows`, then check `if >=1`

But is it faster to do a query with limit 1; ? and check if a row is coming back ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It would be faster to run a `limit 1` query. And if all you're doing is checking for the existence of a row, why bother returning all those columns? Simply select `1`. That will be (negligibly) faster. BTW: Your code looks vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Consider sanitizing the dynamic parts of your query with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or a similar function.

Comment: @Roby: You accepted this answer but then unaccepted it. Why? Do you need any additional clarification?

Answer (score 4):

`LIMIT 1` will have better performance because it will stop matching when the `LIMIT` has been satisfied.

If you only ever expect 1 row, add `LIMIT 1` to your query.

Also, if you are only checking for the presence of that string in the query, there is no need to use column names with `SELECT` in the query. Just use `SELECT 1...`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
select count(*) from user a, verteiler_user b 
     where a.email=\''.$email.'\' and a.kid=' . $kid.' and b.vid=' . $vid . ' and a.uid = b.uid
```

and get the count by:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array(...);
if ($row[0] > 0)  // is there a hit?
   ...
```